# flutter hero widget not working when going to new page

Tags: flutter, hero

i am currently using the hero widget for flutter. my issue is that the hero is only working when i go from profile screen to chat screen and not from chat screen to profile screen. the tags are the same but i just cannot wrap my head around why is it not working. tia for all inputs

chat screen

```
class _AppBarTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  const _AppBarTitle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final channel = StreamChannel.of(context).channel;
    return Row(
      children: [
        Hero(
          tag: 'community-profile-picture',
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4),
            child: Avatar.medium(
                url: Helpers.randomPictureUrl(), // can be a random image url
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      PersonalDevelopmentProfileScreen.routeWithChannel(
                          channel));
                }),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 16,
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              Helpers.getChannelName(channel, context.currentUser!),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 2),
          ],
        )),
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: IconBackground(
              icon: CupertinoIcons.info_circle,
              onTap: () => showDialog<String>(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                  title: Center(
                    child: Text(
                        'About ${Helpers.getChannelName(channel, context.currentUser!)}'),
                  ),
                  content: Text(
                      '${Helpers.getChannelName(channel, context.currentUser!)} Description'),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                          primary: AppColors.accent),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
                      child: const Text('OK',
                          style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.secondary)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

scaffold for chat screen

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leadingWidth: 54,
        leading: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: IconBackground(
            icon: CupertinoIcons.chevron_back,
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(CustomPageRoute(
                child: const HomeScreen(), direction: AxisDirection.right)),
          ),
        ),
        title: const _AppBarTitle(),
      ),
```

profile screen

```
class _AppBarTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  const _AppBarTitle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Members Of Community',
                style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black)),
            const SizedBox(height: 2),
          ],
        )),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 16,
        ),
        Hero(
          tag: 'community-profile-picture',
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4),
            child: Avatar.medium(
                url: Helpers.randomPictureUrl(), // can be a random image url
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

scaffold for profile screen

```
return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leadingWidth: 54,
            leading: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: IconBackground(
                  icon: CupertinoIcons.chevron_back,
                  onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
            ),
            title: const _AppBarTitle(),
          ),
```

avatar

```
class Avatar extends StatelessWidget {
  const Avatar({
    Key? key,
    this.url,
    required this.radius,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  const Avatar.small({
    Key? key,
    this.url,
    this.onTap,
  })  : radius = 18,
        super(key: key);

  const Avatar.medium({
    Key? key,
    this.url,
    this.onTap,
  })  : radius = 26,
        super(key: key);

  const Avatar.large({
    Key? key,
    this.url,
    this.onTap,
  })  : radius = 34,
        super(key: key);

  final double radius;
  final String? url;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: _avatar(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _avatar(BuildContext context) {
    if (url != null) {
      return CircleAvatar(
        radius: radius,
        backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(url!),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
      );
    } else {
      return CircleAvatar(
        radius: radius,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            '?',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: radius),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: create custom route transitions using PageRouteBuilder, here you can follow this tutorial https://medium.com/@JediPixels/flutter-hero-animation-and-pageroutebuilder-transition-dae058d82a36

Comment: Can you update snippet removing outside data that will reproduce the same error

Comment: @Mado is it because i'm using push (MaterialPageRoute) that's why it is not working?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh sorry what do you mean?

Comment: I can find many data like `IconBackground` , `PersonalDevelopmentProfileScreen` `Avatar`... are unknowns. You can reproduce the issue , more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you testing with emulator/simulator?

Comment: @user18309290 an emulator

Comment: Try with a device - I have had a bad experience with emulator and Hero animation.

Comment: what is `Avatar` in this case?

Comment: @user18309290 device shows the same result as well

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it is my stack overflow dp

Comment: I mean `Avatar.medium` any package or custom class .  Also on my test case, seems like everything is working fine

Comment: @YeasinSheikh avatar has been added

Comment: You can bellow approach of having scaffold, hope this will work with this custom Avatar as well.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh can't use scaffold as it is in the AppBar, throwing me with tons of error when incorporating scaffold

Comment: It would be easy if you provide full two sample scaffold widget will reproduce the issue

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i did some testing and found out that if the both widget exists in the AppBar, when going into a new page, the animation won't be displayed

Comment: OK I will test with appBar hero animation?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh edited with 2 scaffolds and yes test with hero animation

Answer (score 0):

Provide hero top level on second widget and follow this pattern,

chat screen

```dart
class _AppBarTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  const _AppBarTitle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: row(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Row row(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Hero(
          tag: 'community-profile-picture',
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => _2AppBarTitle(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Material(
                child: Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text("tap")),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

profile screen

```dart
class _2AppBarTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  const _2AppBarTitle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero(
      tag: 'community-profile-picture',
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            child: Text("pop"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: my actual code looks similar to yours but it isn't working

Comment: will it be different if u change the both body to AppBar instead?

Comment: could be,  I need to the snippet that will reproduce the issue, you can edit current snippet based on your code struct and update the question

Comment: edited my code with what i have currently

Comment: Sorry but I can't see any scaffold which might produce material issue, Sorry cant work current snippet As I requested for two scaffold

Comment: I've tested on appBar title , everything works fine

Comment: both of the hero are tagged to items in AppBar or?

Comment: No second widget should wrap the full scaffold for better animation, you can always test the provided snippet and then provide your feedback